# Aggregate items in dict

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
A = [{u'CI': {u'RP': 1}}, {u'CI': {u'RP': 1}},  {u'JI': {u'RP': 1}}]
```

and I want merge same keys and increment value in dict.

Example:

From these values :

```
{u'CI': {u'RP': 1}}, {u'CI': {u'RP': 1}}
```

I will have:

```
{u'CI': {u'RP': 2}}
```

final list result is:

```
A = [{u'CI': {u'RP': 2}}, {u'JI': {u'RP': 1}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict` from `collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to help here.  This is a `dict` that will create default values for missing keys.  Firstly you'll want a `defaultdict` that has a default value of `0` to do your aggregation.  Next you'll need a `defaultdict` that has the first kind of `defaultdict` as its default so you can build up to the two levels.

```
>>> A = [{u'CI': {u'RP': 1}}, {u'CI': {u'RP': 1}},  {u'JI': {u'RP': 1}}]
>>> B = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> for d in A:
...     for (key,d2) in d.iteritems():
...         for (key2, value) in d2.iteritems():
...             B[key][key2] += value
... 
>>> B.items()
[(u'CI', defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'RP': 2})), (u'JI', defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'RP': 1}))]
```

If you really want a list of single key dicts rather than a single dict with different keys you can convert the `defaultdict` as follows:

```
>>> [{key: dict(value)} for key,value in B.iteritems()]
[{u'CI': {u'RP': 2}}, {u'JI': {u'RP': 1}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method of dict:

```
A = [{u'CI': {u'RP': 1}}, {u'CI': {u'RP': 1}},  {u'JI': {u'RP': 1}}]
B = {}
for i in A:
     k = i.keys()[0]             # k is 'CI' or 'JI' in this case
     B.setdefault(k, {u'RP': 0}) # set the default 'RP' to 0
     B[k]['RP'] += i[k][u'RP']   # add the RP. Because we already 
                                 # set the default to 0 this will not blow up
print B
# {u'CI': {u'RP': 2}, u'JI': {u'RP': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ugly mess will do it, though I bet there's a more clever way to go about this.

It will also work in Python 2, if that is important.

```
A = [{u'CI': {u'RP': 1}}, {u'CI': {u'RP': 1}}, {u'JI': {u'RP': 1}}]
B = {}
for item in A:
    key = item.keys()[0]
    subDict = item.values()[0]
    existingSubDict = B[key] if key in B else {}
    for subKey, value in subDict.iteritems():
        if not subKey in existingSubDict:
            existingSubDict[subKey] = 0
        existingSubDict[subKey] += value
    B[key] = existingSubDict
print B
```

> {u'CI': {u'RP': 2}, u'JI': {u'RP': 1}}

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy I use is the following, where you should 
replace B.initialize() and B.update() with the things you want 
in your specific problem:

```
B = {}
for i in A: 
    if i not in B: 
        B.initialize(i)
    B.update(i,A[i])
```

Let me write a simple example:

```
B = {}
for i in A: 
    if i not in B: 
        B[i] = 0
    B[i] += A[i]
```

your task should be to write it for your problem, I cannot because I don't know how the code you want to write should behave if an element {u'CI': {u'RB': 1,u'RP': 1}} is present.